# How to align logo with navbar when changing size

Tags: css, navbar

I'm a super newbie so please bare with me. I am just experimenting with html and css but cannot get my logo to be in line with the nav bar text. The size it is at now is super small but it's the closest to being in the correct position. Any other size it jumps down from the navbar.

I assigned position absolute to the logo because whenever I altered the size it would also effect the size of the navbar. So that stopped it from happening. I also moved the logo from the id header and wrapped it around a div. Not sure if this is what is causing me extra problems?

Thank you in advance

`

```
<body>

        <div class="logo">
        <a href="#"><img src="./imgs/logo.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>

        <section id="header">

        <div>
            <ul id="navbar">
                <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="shopvhs.html">Shop VHS</a></li>
                <li><a href="shopcassette.html">Shop Cassettes</a></li>
                <li><a href="games.html">Shop Games</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="cart.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-basket-shopping"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
    
</body>
```

`

`

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}



h3, h2, p {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: white;
}

img {
    height: 200px;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
}

/* Header  */

#header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px 80px;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}

.logo {

    position: absolute;
}

#navbar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#navbar li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

#navbar li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #71CFE7;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

#navbar li a:hover,
#navbar li a.active {
    color: white;
}
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use semantic tags, as header and nav, it better solution.

For logo you need size for wrapper (as < a >) and styles for image (width, height, object-fit).
About object-fit you could read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

also I added gap for header, it prefers, than paddings/margins.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}



h3, h2, p {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: white;
}

img {
    height: 200px;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
}

/* Header  */

header {
    display: flex;
    gap: 0 20px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px 80px;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}

.logo {
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
}
.logo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

#navbar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#navbar li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

#navbar li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #71CFE7;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

#navbar li a:hover,
#navbar li a.active {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <header id="header">
<a class="logo" href="#"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/640px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt=""></a>
        <nav>
            <ul id="navbar">
                <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="shopvhs.html">Shop VHS</a></li>
                <li><a href="shopcassette.html">Shop Cassettes</a></li>
                <li><a href="games.html">Shop Games</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="cart.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-basket-shopping"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    
</body>
```

Comment: I'm unable to like your advice because of my new account but truly thank you. I hope learning all this becomes easier with time for me.

Comment: Everything will be easy one day. Just relax and keep coding :-)